# How to contain floats inside a DIV

Tags: html, css, sass, css-float

I have two inline elements within a div. One element is floated to the left and the other to the right. I have used absolute positioning to place the block containing inline elements at the bottom of a DIV.

Problem: The element floating to the right skews out of its container. How can I fix this so that it stays within its container? Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/MjMLZq).

**HTML**

```
 <div class="posts__post">
   <article>
      <a class="posts__post--preview" href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/470/310/food" /></a>
      <a class="posts__post--title" href=""><h1>Bryce Canyon A Stunning U.S Travel Destination</h1></a>
      <div class="posts__post--meta">
        <a class="posts__post__timestamp"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>10 days ago</a>
        <a class="posts__post__tag">Motivation</a> <!-- element floating out --->
     </div>
   </article>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.posts__post{
    height: 400px;
    width: 310px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    //margin-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);

   .posts__post--preview img{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    }

  .posts__post--tag{
      font-size: em(15);
      font-weight: bold;
      color: $light-grey;
   }

  .posts__post--meta{
    color: $light-grey;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
   }

  .posts__post--title, .posts__post--tag, .posts__post--meta{
   margin: 0 25px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-docoration: none;
  }

 .posts__post__timestamp{
  float:left;
  }

 .posts__post__tag{
  float:right;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of margin that you have given to `posts__post--meta`, instead of using margin use padding, and `box-sizing:border-box`

```
.posts__post--meta{
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-docoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

> For more info about [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Your solution and @GVM solution works fine. In this situation i'm not sure who I should upvote and mark as correct. Though I have a question. Why have you added box-sizing?

Comment: The width and height properties include the content, the padding and border, but not the margin., This link may help you http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
.posts__post--meta{
    color: $light-grey;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 0;
    right:0; //add this
    display: block;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a note I have noticed while I'm working on a php application. Using float within a `<div>` is overridding the whole div. to clarify my point. if you have `<div class="page-wrapper">` and within it you have `<div id="img-align">` and it has a float, it override the `"page-wrapper"` and stand alone. don't use it unless you really need it. Thanks